# How to render multiple reactjs elements inside one DIV using typescript (tsx)?

Tags: typescript, render, reactjs

Refer to the code below, I need to render 3 elements / components under the same container.

I tried calling the Render function for each elements but seems the last one replaces the first 2 ones instead of appending to the container.

And the code below doesn't render anything.  So I'm not sure what is the correct way to do that?

There should be a way for ReactJS to render multiple elements inside the same container (div)?

```
let container:Element = document.getElementById(id);

ReactDOM.render([<HelloComponent class="welcome" compiler="TypeScript" framework="ReactJS" />,
    <LabelTextbox type="text" label="Username" model="{model}" />,
    <button onclick="model.validate()">Validate</button>], container);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You need a wrapper. Here is an example to understand it, what you are essentially saying is that you want `foo` to be a `"Hello"` and `123` at the same time :

```
let foo = "Hello" asWellAs 123;
```

This isn't valid JavaScript. However you can wrap it in e.g. a `div` so its back to just one object. That would be similar to :

```
let foo = {a:"Hello", b:123};
```

In many places in react you need a single container.

Comment: I've updated the code putting 3 elements inside [ , , ].  Now it compiles with no errors but the Render method doesn't render anything.

Can ReactJs.Render handle multiple elements?  There should be a way to do that I think.

Answer (score 0):

The `React.createElement` function takes the type of element to be created (if a string is passed it's an HTML element name, but it can also be a reference to a `ReactClass`), then a `props` object, then an undetermined number of children as the following arguments.

You should create a `div` element that contains everything that you need rendered, and then pass that to the `ReactDOM.render` function.

```
React.createElement("div", null, [...yourComponentsHere])
```

comma separated list of children that you want inside the div.

[Here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.createelement) you can find the docs for the `createElement` function.

Once you have created the element, use that in the `ReactDOM.render`.

You cannot have sibling components rendered without a wrapper. You need to put them inside a `div` or any other container.

```
ReactDOM.render( 
   React.createElement('div', null, [...yourComponentsHere]),
   document.getElementById('container')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try closing your elements in a div and pass as string. Instead of [] use "".